# Update data in Firebase with Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an database in Firebase like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHXUJ.png)

So, I want to change the favorite value when user click favorite. I have try something code but it doesnt change favorite value.

```
private void uploadSetFavorite(final boolean isSetFavorite) {

    reference.child(Common.FIREBASE_MUSCLE_EXERCISE_CHEST_TABLE).child(Common.EXERCISE_SET_FAVORITE_PROPERTY).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ExerciseMuscleDetail muscleDetail = snapshot.getValue(ExerciseMuscleDetail.class);

                muscleDetail.setFavorite(isSetFavorite);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

When I debug, dataSnapshot shows{key = favorite, value = null}. 
Someone can help me?

Comment: Check the value for isSetFavorite. Is it really updated or not here : muscleDetail.setFavorite(isSetFavorite); or check by passing static false or true.

Comment: The function when click the favorite icon, it return exactly true or false. But muscleDetail.setFavorite(isSetFavorite); is still not working.

Comment: You want to set change the value of all chests?

Comment: Thank Alex, I want to change value when i click each item in list chests!

Comment: So you want for a particular chest or for all at once? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i want to change value when i click each item in list chest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please try something like :**

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("favourite", true/false);    // with true/false use your desired value
yourDatabaseChildReference.updateChildren(params);

// yourDatabaseChildReference will be your dbName -> table name (chest) -> item name (1 or 2 or so on)
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, i want to update in node 1 or 2..., and your solution is create a new node.

Comment: no no buddy, It won't create a new node. It will update value for favourite  for perticular node

Comment: that is OK, I add hard code : reference.child(Common.FIREBASE_MUSCLE_EXERCISE_CHEST_TABLE).child("1").updateChildren(params); so it is working. But when click each item in list chests, so how can get the item name 1 or 2 or 3 and so more position to update?

Comment: Now i get position, It is helpfully. Thank for your helping!

Comment: Welcome mate!! Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

try without

> .child(Common.EXERCISE_SET_FAVORITE_PROPERTY)

if it still null?

Comment: Use Comment instead of providing answer for single line solution.

Comment: Thank Vadim, it is working but the firebase is still not update favorite data.

Comment: so try to look doc about update data [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update)